# What is the effect of V+ given from bottom in this multivibrator?

Tags: multivibrator, astable, 741-opamp

In the astable multi vibrator, the second figure has a V+ voltage given additionally.

What is the output of that circuit digram compared to first figure?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you try out a circuit simulator? There are free circuit simulators available online. It is the best way to learn. At the positive terminal of the opamp, the voltage you have indicated seems incorrect. When the opamp output is 0V, how much will be the +ve terminal and when the opamp output is +V, how much will be the +ve terminal can you tell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you get when simulating it ...

[image]

And with rail-to-rail opamp

[image]

Comment: here, the output of the opamp is not rail-to-rail. Since the original question seems to be theoretical, I'd use an ideal opamp for simulation so that I will get a theoretical answer where the Vg net swings between +v/3 to +2v/3

Comment: Right. Will add rail-to-rail opamp.